# Continue process run after calling DebugActiveProcess()

Tags: debugging, winapi

I'm trying to build some sort of statistical Profiling application that operates as follows:

1. Attaches it self to a running process (**DebugActiveProcess()**).
2. Enters to some kind of loop that:

   - Commands the process to Break (**DebugBreakProcess()**).
   - Saves it's call stack (or just analyzes it).
   - Continues the process (**ContinueDebugEvent()**).
3. Detaches from the process (**DebugActiveProcessStop()**)

I just can't figure out how to do that.
I understand that i must use the **WaitForDebugEvent()** mechanism somehow but i don't know how.

Moreover, i figured out that after calling **DebugActiveProcess()** the process is halted, but in order to be able to call **ContinueDebugEvent()** i must give it information that is available only after **WaitForDebugEvent()** returns.

What can i do?

Comment: Very unclear.  You have to call WaitForDebugEvent() right after calling DebugActiveProcess().  You'll get a lot of events, last one is EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT for a breakpoint.

Comment: You were right. Also, i figured out (if I'm not wrong) that only the specific thread that is attached to the debugee will receive the events. So, if the main thread of my profiler process attaches itself to the debugee then its threads won't get the events, only he will.
Further question - Why are there so many events at the beginning (among them is the CreateProcess event)? Is this mechanism is a stack like mechanism that holds all the past events until some debugger collects them?

Comment: It is giving you the information a debugger needs.  What DLLs are loaded, what threads are running.

Comment: Another question though...
What happens on a multi-core machine?
Lat's say the debugged process has many threads and it runs on dual-core machine. What happens if, at the moment of sending the EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT event to that process, two of its threads are running, one on each core? What would be the dwThreadId that is returned in the DEBUG_EVENT structure? Maybe the debugger will receive two consecutive EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT events, from each of the currently running threads?

Comment: This too is documented, first thread of the process.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: First thread in chronological mean? The first that was created among all others?

Comment: By the way, I read the documentation you linked and it only talks about the firstly initiated BREAKPOINT_EXCEPTION with which the debugee informs the debugger that he has all the info needed and that it is ready to continue. Am i correct? If so, my question is still open - what does the dwThreadId represents in case it is not that first BREAKPOINT_EXCEPTION?

Answer (score 0):

Check:

https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/dbg_continue-vs-dbg_exception_handled/

DBG_EXCEPTION_HANDLED

Speaking of Wine, browsing through the sources I found several other “undocumented” status codes:

• DBG_TERMINATE_PROCESS
• DBG_TERMINATE_THREAD
• DBG_CONTROL_C
• DBG_CONTROL_BREAK
• DBG_COMMAND_EXCEPTION

However, the last three don’t seem to be supported by Windows XP.